# How to put Folding Menu on the right bottom corner?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code that ive tried: https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/wOqBQr
I put it in the right bottom corner. Apparently,it does not work in this position.
I do not know how to reverse it and still work.

```
.menu {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
.menu:hover {
  pointer-events: all;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
span {
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
.item:hover span {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.menu:hover .spacer:before {
  width: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu:hover .item {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.45s;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

I use just 2 of the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your question and you want to reverse it so it's in the bottom right and not the bottom left. With a few minor changes to the CSS and HTML it's easily do-able:

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
.menu:hover {
  pointer-events: all;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.spacer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  height: 1px;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 0.25s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
  right: 0;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
span {
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
.item:hover span {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.menu:hover .spacer:before {
  width: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu:hover .item {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
.item:nth-child(10) {
  transition-delay: 0.45s;
}
.item:nth-child(9) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.item:nth-child(8) {
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(10) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(9) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(8) {
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.45s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.65s;
}
.menu:hover .item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item"><span>Twitter</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Instagram</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Flickr</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Behance</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>MixCloud</span></div>
   <div class="spacer"></div> 
  <div class="label">Follow Me</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/treefishuk/pen/NWGgLbO

Comment: Exactly! That was what I want to do. Thank you!